# Sci fi book from the 80s where humanity builds a space ship based on alien technology

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

Sorry I do not have much. Here is what I can remember. The parts are disjointed at best.

Humans already have contact with some aliens. One group they do not communicate with and I believe they are a heavy grav species.

Humans are building a space ship based on old old alien tech, or built it to figure out the old old alien tech. The spaceship is privately own via shares, like you would a public company.

One "scoundrel" type of guy owns 1 share and is going to the meeting of the ship or launch. He befriends another guy.

Later they send this ship on a suicide mission into a sun, but someone sends the old old alien tech letters to the other heavy grav alien ship, and that ship saves the one built by humans.

Would not surprise me if some of this book was based on Star Wars, or the other way around.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall the cover of the book?  Was it a paperback or a hardcover?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like the plot of E. E. Doc Smith's Skylark series. Was the bad guy called _DuQuesne_?

Comment: Shades of David Brin's Sundiver, but the plot doesn't quite match unless it is a bit confused in memory...

Comment: DavidW Sorry, I do not recall the cover. It was a paperback, but that does not mean it was never published in hardcover

Comment: John Rennie, I looked at the EE Doc series, and no such luck, but thank you very much

Comment: Basya, please assume I am confused a little and have a bad bad memory of this. I have been hunting for this for some time with limited memories. I looked at sundiver, not it, but looks interesting. I would say the tv series SG1 stole from that!

Comment: Well, too bad about this forum, thought I found a good place, but it appears that there are trolls and stupid people here are well. Wont be back, It is not about just this thread. Wont be back, don't bother responding.